# How to select cases in R?

Tags: r, spss

I'm keen to make the leap from SPSS to R.

A common command used in SPSS is applying filtering. Can somebody please advise on why I am receiving an error message?

```
2019dataset=read.spss("C:\\SPSS data\\2019dataset.sav")

selected_2019dataset <- 2019dataset[ which(2019dataset$hhweight > 0 & 2019dataset$income~=0 & 2019dataset$age > 16 & 2019dataset$age < 59),]
```

I'm getting an error saying that there is an unexpected '='

The filter I am trying to replicate in SPSS syntax is:

```
SELECT IF ((hhweight > 0) AND (income~=0) AND (age > 16 AND age <59)).
```

I've been following the example here:

https://www.statmethods.net/management/subset.html

Grateful for any suggestions.

Thanks.

Comment: The tilde is a function in R, not a negation operator.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `2019dataset$income~=0`

try `2019dataset$income!=0` if you want "not equal to"

or `2019dataset$income==0` if you want "equal to"

Spaces might make reading clearer so `2019dataset$income != 0` or `2019dataset$income == 0` would be an improvement, and you may not need `which`, but these are less important

Comment: Also, check out `?Comparison` for a full list of relational operators in R.

Comment: Thanks very much :)

Comment: If I wanted to recode this from SPSS:

IF ((any (householdtype, 11, 12, 13, 21, 42, 33)) AND (sex = 1)) hhsex = 1.

into R:

hhtype_selected_dataset <- VF_2017_18[ which(dataset2019$householdtype = 11 | dataset2019$householdtype = 12 | dataset2019$householdtype = 13 | dataset2019$householdtype = 21 | dataset2019$householdtype = 42 | dataset2019$householdtype = 33 & dataset2019$sex = 1 ), ]

It would be done like this? Grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: R uses `==` here but you can also use `%in%` as with hhtype_selected_dataset <- VF_2017_18[ dataset2019$householdtype %in% c(11, 12,  13, 21, 42, 33) & dataset2019$sex == 1 ), ]   and

Answer (score 2):

I transitioned from SPSS to R and I prefer to use the tidyverse package, which I think is a bit more intuitive.

Your code would look something like:

```
library(tidyverse)    
selected_2019dataset <- 2019dataset %>%
    filter(hhweight > 0 & income == 0 & age > 16 & age < 59)
```

Comment: Looks good! I'll move onto this alternative once I get to grips with R :)